# sub query causing issue with INTERVAL 90 DAY

Tags: date, subquery

```
    $query = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `name` LIKE '%$search%' 
        OR (number IN (
            SELECT number FROM `posts` WHERE `name` LIKE '%$search%'
         AND `number` !='')
     )
order by date ASC LIMIT 100");
```

Where should I plug in this line? I haven't been able to get it to work with the above query. thx.

```
 && date>=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY)
```

(All rows returned must be INTERVAL 90 DAY...including subquery part)

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `name` LIKE 'adam'
&& date>=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) 
OR (number IN (
    SELECT number FROM `posts` WHERE `name` LIKE 'adam'
AND `number` !='')
)
```

This will not return any results if adam row is older than 90 days.
however, when adam row less than 90 days, results from the subquery rows can be expired.

So I tried this but still bypassing date check for subquery:

```
 $query = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `name` LIKE 'adam'
&& date>=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) 
OR (number IN (
    SELECT number FROM `posts` WHERE `name` LIKE 'adam'
AND `number` !=''
&& date>=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) )
)
```